# edit in angularjs using php

Tags: php, angularjs

i wish to fetch the values to be edited, in the textbox, i.e. 1st the textboxes will be empty, then when user clicks on the edit link the values should be filled in the textbox. User can change the values, click on save button and the new values will be updated. following is the code:

html code:
    
                
                Save

controller:

```
$scope.fetch = function(id) {
            var elem = angular.element($element);
            var dt = $(elem).serialize();
            dt = dt+"&id="+id;
            dt = dt+"&action=fetch";
            alert(dt);
            console.log($(elem).serialize());
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'php/products.php',
                data: dt,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                //~ $scope.status = status;
                //~ $scope.data = data;
                $scope.rs = data;
                console.log($scope.rs); // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                $scope.status = status;
            });
        };
```

products.php:

```
if($action == 'fetch') {
$query = '
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    product
WHERE 
    `product_id` ="' . $_POST['id'] . '"
';
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error()); 
$data = array();
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
echo json_encode($row);
//print_r($row);
```

}

this code is not working- when user clicks on edit link of any user, the textboxes get filled with the value- Object object. If ti print the value then it gets printed but when i try to assign it to the textbox, it gets filled with Object object.
where am i getting wrong? how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery to get/set fields anymore if you're using Angular.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="field1">
```

Controller:

```
//set
$scope.field1 = obj.field1;

//get
var f1 = $scope.field1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the `angular.fromJson` function when receiving the response

```
.success(function(json, status) {
                data=angular.fromJson(json);
                //~ $scope.status = status;
                //~ $scope.data = data;
                $scope.rs = data;
                console.log($scope.rs); // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
            })
```

You might want to take a look into [AngularPHP](https://github.com/urigoren/angularphp) and save some time,